# Setting Schema as a run time argument in Datafusion wrangler is not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

We have a requirement to pass on Output Schema of the wrangler as a run time arguments

Below are the formats we tried but nothing seems to work, can any one guide us on how to provide schema as a run time argument through UI or  Rest API Call

```
[
    {
        "name": "etlSchemaBody",
        "schema": {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "etlSchemaBody",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "body_1",
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "body_2",
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "body_3",
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "body_4",
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "null"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "body_5",
                    "type": [
                        "string",
                        "null"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

```
"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"etlSchemaBody\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"body_1\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"body_2\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"body_3\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"body_4\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"body_5\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]}]}"
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more about what the process you are trying to set up is for. For instance, what is the end of the pipeline ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"etlSchemaBody\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"body_1\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"body_2\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"body_3\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"body_4\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"body_5\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]}]}"
```

use

```
{"type":"record","name":"etlSchemaBody","fields":[{"name":"body_1","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"body_2","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"body_3","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"body_4","type":["string","null"]},{"name":"body_5","type":["string","null"]}]}
```

as the value for your schema macro.

My guess is that your pipeline run failed with malformed JSON error.

If this does not work, please post logs from the pipeline run.

Comment: yes the pipeline failed with malformed json error.Thank you, will try this out

Comment: @phaneendrakumar what was the result? was it successful?